# How to add a true/false to a disjunction/conjunction in nhibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, criteria, nhibernate-criteria

I saw a few older posts mentioning `MyDisjunction.Add(Restrictions.Sql("(1=1)"))`, but I couldn't find the Sql function (does it still exist?).

Instead, I am using `MyDisjunction.Add(Restriction.Where<MyObject>(x => x.SomeProperty == x.SomeProperty))` (!= for false), but this feels like I'm abusing the use of `Restriction.Where`.  Is there something more natural to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [class Expression](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Criterion/Expression.cs)

```
var alwaysTrue = Expression.Sql("1 = 1");

...
   .Add(alwaysTrue)
```

But this is a code snippet from [Expression class](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Criterion/Expression.cs) source:

```
namespace NHibernate.Criterion
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class is semi-deprecated. Use <see cref="Restrictions"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="Restrictions"/>
    public sealed class Expression : Restrictions
    ...
```

Comment: Any options that aren't deprecated (or semi so)?

Comment: I'm accepting as a depricated answer is better than none, but I'm still open to a non-(semi-)deprecated solution.